# A js code is working fine from developer tool but not from js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can run the following code from my developer console:

```
  jQuery(".skiptranslate").contents().filter(function () {
        alert('works again');
        return this.nodeType != 1;
    }).replaceWith("");
```

But when I put this same code in js file it has no effect. I put this code in js file inside `$(document).ready()` function. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the element `.skiptranslate` added dynamically?

Comment: Can you try putting a [break-point](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#loc) in your JS file at the location where you have `jQuery("..` and then type `jQuery(".skiptranslate")` in the console? If it returns an object with length as 0, then the selector you passed was not in the DOM when you ran this code

Comment: By the time your `jQuery(document).ready()` function executes, the element with class `skiptranslate` is not yet there in DOM.

Comment: Yes. .skiptranslate element is added dynamically. @Tushar

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan, then you should run this code, after your element gets injected in DOM or network/API call gets completed.

Comment: How can I do this. I want to write this custom jquery code in a separate js file. So how can I check My element is injected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive function to check if `skiptranslate` is ready (rendered/loaded) using `$('.skiptranslate').length`. If founded run your code if not, wait 100ms then call yourself (do another check), keep check until you found the element.

Use setTimeout to set the delay, my example here is 100ms.

Don't forget to init the function for the first time `skiptranslateFn();`

My example here simulated the class `skiptranslate` to be added after 1sec (1000ms).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function skiptranslateFn() {
    if ($('.skiptranslate').length) {
      jQuery(".skiptranslate").contents().filter(function() {
        alert('works again');
        return this.nodeType != 1;
      }).replaceWith("");
      console.log('---skiptranslate FOUNDED! ----');
    } else {
      console.log('skiptranslate not found yet');
      setTimeout(function() {
        skiptranslateFn()
      }, 100);
    }
  }
  //init
  skiptranslateFn();

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#test').addClass('skiptranslate');
    console.log('element loaded!');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  test div
</div>
```